# How can I install my dryer exhaust - Should I contact the builder?

Tags: dryer, vent, exhaust

I am trying to install my new LG dryer exhaust in a new build home and the part attached to the wall just fell off. Should I contact the builder?

I have done this before and it was not as complicated.

See images below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/854XB.jpg

Comment: why are you asking instead of doing? ... ask the builder ... that may be covered by a new house warranty

Comment: It looks like the adjustable 90 broke. If the duct is metal it may have a screw in it to hold it together in the wall.